# How to return async function Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Hey here is my async js function that i want to execute and return the value .

```
async function matcheslol() {
    let allmatches=[]
    let matches = document.getElementsByClassName('EventCellstyles__Link-sc-1m83enb-0 dhKVQJ')
    for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        let details = (matches[i].innerText).split('\n').slice(2, 4);
        let matchname = details.join(' - ');
        console.log(matchname)
        matches[i].firstChild.click()
        await sleep(3000)
        let votes = document.getElementsByClassName('styles__VotingWrapper-sc-1f9zoyc-1 iOsjnp')[0].innerText.split('\n').slice(0,3)
        let date = document.getElementsByClassName('styles__Wrapper-sc-1c9nn5b-0 HoJZc ps ps--active-y')[1].getElementsByClassName('Content-sc-1o55eay-0 gYsVZh')[0].innerText
        let dict={'DATE':date,'MatchTitle':matchname,'Votes':votes}
        allmatches.push(dict)
    }
    return allmatches
}
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
  
matcheslol()
```

Python :

```
data=driver.execute_async_script(script_mentioned_above)
```

I get this error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: script timeout`

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it:

```py
# Create the script you want
my_script = '''
async function matcheslol() {
  // Your previous function here...
}

// Set it to window so we can use it later
window.matcheslol = matcheslol;
'''

# Set window variable
driver.execute_script(my_script)
# Execute the function and return the value
value = driver.execute_script('return window.matcheslol().then(r => r);')
```

Comment: What if I don't want the value to be globally acessible?